# How to send transaction to 1 specified block?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, web3.py, ethereumjs

I'm interact with Ethereum using Web3js . How to send transaction to 1 specified block ?

**CASE :**  I want to send transaction to specified  block is **1111**  . I have tried listening Block Number but when sending transaction it is usually 2-3 Blocks slower. Is there any way I can correctly send to this Block? .

Answer (score 1):

> CASE : I want to send transaction to specified block is 1111

You don't. Unless you are a miner yourself, you cannot insert transaction to a specific block.

[Read about Ethereum transaction lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65842575/315168).

Comment: I accept to pay high gas fees to send for the correct block. Is there no other way?

Comment: It does not matter how high gas fees you pay, there is no guarantee that your transaction will be any specific block. It is impossible.

Comment: This way also is not 100% guarantee but there is some chance if you will use Flashbot eth_sendBundle : https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/miners/mev-geth-spec/v02-rpc   Parameter:  blockNumber - Exact block number at which the bundle can be included.  https://github.com/flashbots/ethers-provider-flashbots-bundle/blob/994b3624dfb7c23c4cf82e0c1550050ea0208525/src/index.ts#L323